# What is this Soviet Uniform? Made in 1975

Tags: soviet-union, uniform

I recently got this uniform off a Russian website, but I the website did't specify which it was, and I haven't been able to identify it using google searches? Anyone here know?

[image]

Comment: It might help if you posted where you got it from. (Looks unauthentic to me, as the front pouches are missing.)

Comment: The shirt and belt do NOT look like a common Soviet uniform of 1975.

Comment: It's pretty close to http://www.vedomstva-uniforma.ru/forma1973/ris65.jpg (regular infantry field uniform) though we can't see the noticeable pockets of the shirt, are they there?

Comment: @seven-phases-max What your pic displays would likely be wool/serge. The Op pic looks like cotton. (at)Some Random: What does the label say?

Comment: @LangLangC Indeed. I've looked in more sources and it seems the originally it (the shirt of 70s) should be wool. But then there is also "lighter" version "for hot regions" where it may be cotton (e.g. [the privite on the left](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Военная_форма_Советской_армии#/media/File:Afgan1987_Gardez_UAZ469.jpg)) - though on the official drawings both variants look [the same](http://www.vedomstva-uniforma.ru/forma1973/ris20.jpg) (probably it's just not very accurate "texture" of the drawings).

Comment: @seven-phases-max The pockets are there, just obscured by my arms. I can take another pic if needed. I think the answer you first gave is what I was looking for though.

Answer (score 1):

The belt is certainly ***not*** authentic (it is nothing even remotely close to anything ever used by the Soviet Army).

The pants might be [gallifet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galliffet_trousers)-style, but they were long gone by 1970-ies.

The shirt lacks pockets and is buttoned the wrong way.

The preponderance of evidence points to the "uniform" being fake.

Source: I lived in the USSR and I remember how soldiers looked like.
See also https://forma-odezhda.ru/encyclopedia/voennaya-forma-sovetskoj-armii/

Comment: There may be never issued surplusses lingering in a warehouse… Cut, cloth, colour & construction, all somehow off. But it is hard to prove a negative, and I obviously agree that this is most likely 'military chic' or just fake.

Answer (score 0):

Uniform looks consistent with [Soviet Army uniform](https://tipolog.livejournal.com/5448.html), except for the belt.

Comment: and except for the front pouches on the shirt?

Comment: and the different cut of the shoulders and sleeves, the different cuffs (the drawing doesn't even show cuffs on the shirt), and the colouration (the Soviet uniform was more green, though this could be a regional variation).